# Различие между лямбдами и ссылками на методы

Tags: java, lambda, лямбда-выражение

есть код:

```
interface A{
    int gg(int a);
}

class Main{
    
    static int test(double a){
        return 3;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1 OK
        A a = Main::test;
        //2 error: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
        A aa = (double n) -> 3;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** почему первая запись отлично компилируется, а вторая выдаёт ошибку? Ведь они означают одно и тоже.

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы заталкиваете вместо инта дабл. так все работает:

```
interface A {

    int gg(int a);
}
class Main {

    static int test(double a) {
        return 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1 OK
        A a = Main::test;
        //2 error: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
        A aa = (int n) -> 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: нутк в первом же случае я тоже заталкиваю вместо инта дабл, но всё отлично работает.

Comment: в джаве еще есть приведение типов. инт всегда можно привести к дабл. а вот наоброт уже нет. вы, разумеется, можете отсечь дробную часть, но это другая история. вопрос в том, что автоматическое приведение типов не работает. в первом случае вы подставляете метод, принимающий дабл, под лямбду, которая затолкает туда инт и проблем нет. но в момент , когда вы явно определили параметры в таком виде (int n) -> 3; автоматическое приведение типов не работает, ведь вы их определили явно и код не компилируется.

Comment: проблема в том, что выражения Main::test и (double n) -> 3; не равнозначны. равнозначными будет Main::test и n -> 3;

Comment: то есть получается указывать типы параметров лямбды нужно только для того чтобы просто повторить типы которые указаны в сигнатуре абстрактного метода. интересно для чего это вообще нужно делать ?

Comment: поймите простую вещь: в лямбде вы фактически переопределяете метод интерфейса. попробуйте унаследоваться от интерфейса и переопределить метод. получиться у вас вместо инта дабл подставить или не объявить тип данных? тоже самое и лямбда, просто в случае с последней, с учетом того, что лямбда сама по себе является упрощенным выражением, вам позволяется в рамках этого самого упрощения не определять типы данных, однако строгую типизацию по прежнему никто не отменял. и типы данных из метода никуда не исчезли. и, разумеется, раз они есть, вы можете их указать в явном виде